# Git push through Android studio is freezing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've made a lot of commits today to a repository, and all of a sudden Android studio cannot push to the repo. The progress bar at the bottom simply freezes. In version control it says this:

```
21:53:59.573: [Blastar] git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master
Counting objects: 28, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: I suppose this is an AS issue, which came about with a recent update.  Actually, it does pushes it, as it could be  seen from the log, but the AS process never finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assumption: you have tried restarting AS and or computer as a fix.

Have you tried to push not using AS? For example open a command prompt and doing it through there? Looks like you are using git, should be real easy just navigate to the folder that contains the hidden git repo folder, type git push and it is done (since you already committed changes)

Have you tried pushing another project as a test? This ensures the issue is not with your repo server.

Answer (score 4):

Push by using git: open project folder path in command prompt.

Do following commands:

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "your message"`
3. `git push -u origin master`
4. Enter your password.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem when rebasing and cloning via Android Studio.

This helped:

Settings -> Git -> Use credentials helper (switch)